# Biometric Template cannot save in MySQL database because it is null

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fingerprint, biometrics

I searched and tried some codes to save the enrolled fingerprints from the scanner but my error was "id and FP couldn't be null". I know that there is something wrong with the codes i used. I am using OTW SDK of Digital Persona. VB.net as prog.language and MySql as my database. Thank you for helping me solved this problem.

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = ("Server = localhost; User Id= root; Password =1234;Database = dbpayroll")
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

    Try
        conn.Open()

        For Each template As DPFP.Template In Data.Templates

            If Not template Is Nothing Then

                cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO employeefp " +
                              "SET id=@id, " +
                              "FP=@FP " +
                              " ", conn)

                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@id", Me.TextBox1.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@FP", template.Bytes))

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                MessageBox.Show("Template Successfuly Saved.", "Finger Enrolled")
            End If
        Next

        conn.Close()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(myerror.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nothing is stored in your `@id,@FP`  parameters and you columns in your storage table are declared as `NOT NULL`.

Try to echo them before insert so you can make sure there is some data passed to them !

Comment: I tried showing it up using message box before the insert command. first, textbox have data showed up. but same error after. Second thing is when i messagedbox the templates.bytes, I got no data.

Comment: why don't you alter you table definition to accept NULL values  and run again, and next see what is stored in the table.

Comment: This answers my problem. thank you for helping me out.